# send value to overlay from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am displaying a overlay on click of a row in the table. The over lay is a div
 in the same page. This is working perfectly fine. But now my requirement is like if
 i click on row 1 it should display the row 1 and if row 2 is clicked it should 
display the row 2 and so on. But the problem is i can know the row clicked from the 
jquery. On click i show a overlay div. In the i load a php view using the code igniter.
 Now i need to know in the php server side which row i had clicked for the overlay to 
come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use identifiers on each of the table rows?

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr id="row1" onClick="myMethod(this.id);">
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
         function myMethod(rowID){
              //OPEN LAYER 
              //send information via XHR (XmlHttpRequest) INCLUDE the rowID in the REQUEST
             //DISPLAY THE XHR Response in the LAYER
         }
</script>
```

If i am correct you need to know which row triggered the request so you can show the correct response. For that as i explained use an identifier like the ID attribute.